# How do I disable Dock and Panel transparency?

Tags: gnome-shell, panel, ubuntu-dock, dock, transparency

See the image below. The transparency is a bit much, and makes it difficult to see the Panel icons. How do I disable it?

[image]

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10.

Answer (score 5):

To force Ubuntu Dock to assume a fixed opacity, open Terminal and run

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock transparency-mode 'FIXED'
```

Also you can change `max-alpha` and `min-alpha` (0 is completely transparent, 1 is completely opaque) of Ubuntu Dock following this:
[How to make Ubuntu Dock fully opaque (black, like the top bar) when apps are touching it/fullscreen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/975791/how-to-make-ubuntu-dock-fully-opaque-black-like-the-top-bar-when-apps-are-tou)

---

Getting rid of top-bar transparency is a bit tricky. You may use "*Dynamic Panel Transparency*" extension from [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1011/dynamic-panel-transparency/).

Once installed reload the page, a settings icon should appear. Click on it, a dialogue should pop up. Go to *Background* tab, toggle on "*Enable custom opacity*" and set "*Unmaximized opacity*" to a very high value, say 100%.

[image]

Then log out and log in again.

Alternatively you may try a different shell theme without a transparent top bar.

Comment: Is there any GUI that one could use to tweak `gsettings`?

Comment: @alexis You may use `dconf-editor`.