# How to make Ubuntu Dock fully opaque (black, like the top bar) when apps are touching it/fullscreen?

Tags: 17.10, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, ubuntu-dock

I've tried changing the `stylesheet.css` file located at `/usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com` and ended up making the dock dark when the top bar is translucent and still translucent when the top bar is black.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open Terminal and run the following command first to allow custom alpha values for the dock

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock customize-alphas true
```

Then run the following to set the maximum alpha value to be 1 (i.e. completely opaque)

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock max-alpha 1.0
```

Then log out and log in again.