# Full transparency on Ubuntu 19.04 dock

Tags: gnome-shell, 19.04, ubuntu-dock, transparency

How can I set Ubuntu 19.04'S dock to transparent? I have already set:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock customize-alphas true
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock min-alpha 0
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock max-alpha 0
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock background-opacity 0
```

But none of this works. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes I have restarted the computer

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/q/972385/480481

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to also use `transparency-mode` with `FIXED` value:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.extensions.dash-to-dock transparency-mode FIXED
```